# Какие правила употребления и склонения китайских фамилий, стоящих в тексте без имени?

Tags: склонение, общие-вопросы, ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Китайские имена **пишутся в два слова** *фамилия + имя* и **склоняется только последняя часть** (имя).

Если *Чжан Юань* — мужчина: *для Чжан Юаня, к Чжан Юаню, о Чжан Юане* и пр.

Также есть еще одно правило: **женские китайские имена и фамилии не склоняются** никогда.

Если *Чжан Юань* — женщина: *для Чжан Юань, к Чжан Юань, о Чжан юань* и пр.

Но очень мало официальных подтвержденных сведений о ситуации, когда китайская мужская фамилия стоит в тексте без имени или когда она употребляется с титулом или обращением. Например:

*У господина Цзинь* или *у господина Цзиня*? *К императору Суй* или *к императору Сую*? *С Чжан* или *с Чжаном*?

Можете объяснить этот момент и сказать, в каком справочнике это описано?

И можно ли вообще использовать в тексте китайскую фамилию без обращения или имени? Потому что в китайских книгах чаще всего стоит именно *фамилия + имя*, а отдельно имя применяется только при обращении к близкому человеку. Да и китайским этикетом принято всегда при обращении к кому-то в связке с фамилией использовать должность, титул либо что-то подобное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Если встречается одна фамилия (без имени) или одно имя (без фамилии), то они склоняются по общим правилам, т. е. Оуяна, Чжана, Таньтаю, Вану и т. д.
```

[Концевич Л.Р. Китайские имена собственные и термины в русском тексте (Пособие по транскрипции). — М.: Муравей, 2002 (см. с. 92)](https://studylib.ru/doc/2184125/)

Т. е. в ваших примерах:

- у господина Цзиня
- к императору Сую
- с Чжаном

**P.S.** Возможен случай, когда последний слог имени (в написании "фамилия + имя") по правилам не может быть изменен. В справочниках этот случай не найден, но встречается рекомендация (на основании практических примеров из лит. переводов), когда по причине несклоняемости имени склоняется фамилия. https://redaktor.ucoz.net/publ/1-1-0-2

Comment: Здравствуйте, Александр! Давно вас не видно здесь было. Очень рад вас видеть снова!!

Comment: Вам нравится такой вариант цитирования, когда ползунком надо прокручивать содержимое?

Comment: Артём, интерфейс изменился и стал непривычным, я пока не нашел другого варианта. :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Да, я тоже долго привыкнуть к нему не мог. ;)